# Is there anyway to unregister from APNS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I registered myself to APNS while testing. I am able to get my device token in `application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken`

But how do I unregister myself so I will be prompted to receive push notifications again?

Have tried deleting the app and resetting `Reset Location & Privacy`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Apple docs on Troubleshooting Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42):

> ### Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS
>
> The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app.
>   Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again
>   unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at
>   least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave
>   the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without
>   actually waiting a day by following these steps:
>
> 1. Delete your app from the device.
> 2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
> 3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
> 4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.